# Maven build error : java:[6,39] cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting below error while trying to build war file with maven build.

```
[ERROR] /C:/Users/skarakka/Documents/Eworkspace/cim/src/main/java/com/ui/servicewrappers/db/DBConnectionHandler.java:[6,39] cannot find symbol    
symbol:   class HttpTransportProperties    
location: package org.apache.axis2.transport.http    
[ERROR] /C:/Users/skarakka/Documents/Eworkspace/cim/src/main/java/com/dnb/applications/webservice/schema/DnBAPI13Stub.java:[265068,48]
```

### package org.apache.axis2.databinding does not exist

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project cim: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: /C:/Users/skar/Documents/Eworkspace/cim/src/main/java/com/cim/customui/servicewrappers/dnb/DBConnectionHandler.java:[6,39] cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class HttpTransportProperties [ERROR] location: package org.apache.axis2.transport.http [/C:/Users/skarDocuments/Eworkspace/cim/src/main/java/com/db/applications/webservice/schema/DBAPI13Stub.java:[265068,48] package org.apache.axis2.databinding does not exist

Comment: Sounds like your dependencies are incomplete. You are missing the library in your setup that provides org.apache.axis2.databinding

Comment: What is the point of putting more such messages into comments? A) read about [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Probably the maven folks would want to see your maven configuration! B) never put such stuff into comments. Always update your question instead. And C), as said: your problem are most likely missing dependencies. You have to tell maven which libraries you need for your project!

Comment: This is what I am getting error, couldn't update that in question due to some issues...

Comment: I've this dependency added for axis2, Is it not enough ? <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: There should be an edit link below the question!

Comment: Ok, can you let me know what dependency missing here ? I tried updating the depenecies, mvn install after deleting .m2 folders etc. It's always compiling during run time compilation. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

After adding "axis2-adb" dependency in POM.XML fixed issue.